# pandas: efficient way to a filter out a few rows (outliers) from a large DataFrame

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe, indexing

I am looking for an efficient way to a filter out a few rows (outliers) from a large DataFrame. According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#delete, the advice is to select the rows that should remain. Here is an example DataFrame -

```
In [288]: dai                                                                                        
Out[288]: 
                   x   y
frame face lmark        
1     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
2     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
3     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
4     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
...               ..  ..
5146  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5147  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5148  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5149  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5150  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN

[312814 rows x 2 columns]
```

whose index is sorted -

```
In [295]: dai.equals(dai.sort_index())                                                               
Out[295]: True
```

now I extract unique sorted values of `frame` index except for the last one (frame 5150) -

```
n [305]: frames = dai.index.get_level_values('frame').drop_duplicates().sort_values()[:-1]          

In [306]: frames                                                                                     
Out[306]: 
Int64Index([   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
            ...
            5140, 5141, 5142, 5143, 5144, 5145, 5146, 5147, 5148, 5149],
           dtype='int64', name='frame', length=5149)
```

and then filter rows in the DataFrame using `.loc`

```
In [307]: dai.loc[frames]                                                                            
Out[307]: 
                   x   y
frame face lmark        
1     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
2     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
3     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
4     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
...               ..  ..
5145  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5146  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5147  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5148  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5149  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
```

The result is correct but it took longer than expected -

```
In [308]: timeit dai.loc[frames]                                                                     
7.31 s ± 83.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [309]: prun -l 4 dai.loc[frames]                                                                  
         1159551 function calls (1138939 primitive calls) in 7.753 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 253 to 4 due to restriction <4>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     5148    3.544    0.001    3.544    0.001 base.py:241(_outer_indexer)
    10298    1.963    0.000    1.963    0.000 {method 'searchsorted' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    10298    0.811    0.000    0.900    0.000 base.py:1588(is_monotonic_increasing)
     5149    0.413    0.000    0.413    0.000 {method 'nonzero' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

Is there any way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it is much quicker to filter a DataFrame with default RangeIndex than using multiIndex